# Not able retrieve the key value from shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am working on the shell script to read config properties from  a .properties files, below is the sample config

```
RCTP_servername=test1
RCTP_databasename=test2
RCTP_portnumber=test3
RCTP_username=test4
RCTP_password=test5
```

i have written a shell script as below but it doesn't work  could anyone please have look and guide me how to solve this

```
#building the keys based on environment
environment=RCTP
servername_key="$environment"_servername
databasename_key="$environment"_databasename
portnumber_key="$environment"_portnumber
username_key="$environment"_username
password_key="$environment"_username

#read the config.properties files 


file=serverconfig.properties
if [ -f "$file" ]
then
 echo "$file found."

 while IFS='=' read -r key value
 do
  key=$(echo $key )
  eval "${key}='${value}'"
 done < "$file"

servername_value=${servername_key}
databasename_value=${databasename_key}
portnumber_value=${portnumber_key}
username_value=${username_key}
password_value=${password_key}
else
  echo "$file not found."
fi
echo  "$servername_value"
```

but am getting an below when i tried to run it, the error is  `./test_script_fte.sh: line 23: ${servername_key}: bad substitution`

The expected output is when `echo $servername_value` executed is `test1`

Comment: I suggest to `source` your properties file.

Comment: @Cyrus could you please let me know what is this `source` don't mind am knew to shell scripting.

Comment: Your file `serverconfig.properties` already has the correct format for bash. Use `source serverconfig.properties` and you can use all variables from your file, e.g.: `echo "$RCTP_servername"`

Comment: @AdarshHDDev: Add a line `source config.properties` at the beginning of script after `#!/bin/bash` in your actual script.

Comment: @AdarshHDDev: Works fine for me. Did you run with the she-bang line added (`#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh`)?

Comment: @Cyrus i used the `source serverconfig.properties` but here if you see `RCTP` is environment which will be input to my script so am going to build `RCTP_servername` using varible `"$environment"_servername`  this will be saved into  `servername_key` variable so based on the value of `servername_key` it should return me the values but its not working.

Comment: @Inian :  i haven't added #!/bin/bash in script will add and check

Comment: @Inian :  i added `#!/bin/bash` and also the `source serverconfig.properties` its not working for me am still getting the same error `./test_script_fte.sh: line 25: ${servername_key}: bad substitution` did you run the same script which is posted in my question ?

Comment: Which Linux variant are you using? Also can you output `bash --version`?

Comment: @Inian  the bash  --version gave me this `x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu`

Comment: @Inian i have one more question did your output returned the value as `RCTP_servername` or the `test1`. because here what I am trying to achieve is  when i pass `RCTP_servername` it should return me value `test1`.  Since the `RCTP_servername` is saved in variable when i do ${servername_key} instead of returning the `test1` its returning me the key name which is `RCTP_servername`.  please let me know if i made my self clear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129864/discussion-between-adarsh-h-d-dev-and-inian).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though `eval` is not recommended most of the time, here is a solution that uses [indirect-reference](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ivr.html) as

```
echo  "${!servername_value}"
```

I have also tweaked the logic to `source` the properties file over using `eval` from your logic. With the complete script as below.

```
#!/bin/bash

#building the keys based on environment

environment=RCTP
servername_key="$environment"_servername
databasename_key="$environment"_databasename
portnumber_key="$environment"_portnumber
username_key="$environment"_username
password_key="$environment"_username

#read the config.properties files 


file=serverconfig.properties

if [ -f "$file" ]
then
    echo "$file found."

    # sourcing the properties file in the current shell to fetch the values

    source "$file"

    servername_value=${servername_key}
    databasename_value=${databasename_key}
    portnumber_value=${portnumber_key}
    username_value=${username_key}
    password_value=${password_key}
else
    echo "$file not found."
fi

echo  "${!servername_value}"
echo  "${!databasename_value}"
echo  "${!portnumber_value}"
echo  "${!username_value}"
echo  "${!password_value}"
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to use the value of a variable as the name of another variable. 
please replace your last line with followings

```
eval echo \"\$$servername_value\"
```

Comment: but i need to assign it to a variable, so that i can use those values later down in my  script

Comment: Thanks it worked i did little modification `eval SERVERNAME=\"\$$servername_value\"
echo "$SERVERNAME"`